# Gradle error when trying to compile an old project Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to re-compile one project that worked fine several months ago and I am getting a gradle error like this one:

> Error:(1, 0) Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.Project.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes

I have updated the gradle version in the `build.gradle` file (project) from

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

I have followed the suggestions of AS with no luck.

Could you give an advice?

My `build.gradle` file (app) is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.aabcdata.learn.german.hd'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 6
        versionName '1.5'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics_3.3.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/AppTracker.jar')
    compile files('libs/presage-lib-1.6.0.jar')
}
```

I have done a Invalidate `Cache/Restart`, as well

Comment: your compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion should have the same major version.

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem also in a very old project. You need to upgrade the gradle distribution version in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. I changed it from version `2.2.1` to `4.1`.

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`